# Rollback not working in MySQL 5.0.96

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, rollback

Rollback not working in MySQL

The user table engine is [InnoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB).

This is what I have.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_innodb';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| have_innodb   | YES   |
+---------------+-------+


mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| version                 | 5.0.96-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | unknown-linux-gnu            |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+


CREATE TABLE `k_customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  ..  
  `updated` timestamp NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=93 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is what I try to test:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO `k_customer` VALUES ('91', .. , '2013-04-21 21:48:46');
ROLLBACK;
```

and it inserts the record...

I even tried

```
ALTER TABLE `k_customer` ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

but it does not help.

There is no such problem on my local DB

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 1.1.8                        |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.5.24-log                   |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86                          |
| version_compile_os      | Win64                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

I know there are heaps of the questions like this. I read many of them and I post here all data that might be relevant to the issue because the misuse of it may cause the exact problem as I have. But all the other answered question do not help me.

Comment: have you set "SET autocommit = 0;" ?

Comment: Actually, I have tried this but, as I know, it does not matter if you start transaction explicitly with 'START TRANSACTION;'.

Comment: Sorry for my previous comment, you right. BTW, your script works fine on my machine Mysql 5.5.31 on Ubuntu (x86_64)

Comment: Yes, it might be bug. We are hosting site on MySQL 5.0.96 and our provider does not do updates for some reasons.